# c# access to all available css list or collection of properties

Tags: c#, .net, css, class, ienumerable

how can i get a list of all `Style` properties available ?

like in the visual studio desingner mode there's an IntelliSense properties list for each element supported,
so as soon as you type `style=` you get offerd by all available properties.

i would like to have it available as a collection or list in code behind too.
shouldn't it be available in a well known .net built in public `class` ?

i was searching the `System.Web.UI.CssStyleCollection` but couldn't get it through any method yet. i am sure it is (should be) very simple .
thanks in advance !

as explained in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.cssstylecollection.keys.aspx) :

CssStyleCollection for the **specified** HTML server control

i was trying to have all available properties not only those applied on a given element or control in a given page.
thanks for your comment @Abody97

Comment: See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.cssstylecollection.aspx). Won't `System.Web.UI.CssStyleCollection.Keys` do what you want?

Comment: tried it last night , how can i enumerate on it ? (i am updating my post) with your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found only source to be [HtmlTextWriterStyle Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriterstyle.aspx) so to avoid use of long name

`HtmlTextWriterStyle.SomeProperty.ToString()`

```
    public sealed class StlProps
    {
       // in visual studio you can just mark the HtmlTextWriterStyle 
       // hit "F12" to its definition to have a list of properties
       // just copy it as const strings 
      public const string BgColor = "BackgroundColor",
                          BackgroundImage = "BackgroundImage",
                          BorderCollapse = "BorderCollapse", 
                          ...etc'

    }
```

this will let you set control style as follows

```
controlID.Style.Add(stlProps.BgColor, "value from Color Class");
```